# When i try to add vue js in laravel shows an error -> Error: Cannot find module 'webpack/lib/rules/DescriptionDataMatcherRulePlugin'

Tags: laravel, vue.js, vuejs2

[image]

I am using the following code to add vue js in laravel application.

```
composer require laravel/ui
php artisan ui vue
npm install
npm run watch-poll
npm mix "--watch" "--watch-poll"
npm run development -- --watch "--watch-poll"
npm run dev
```

Answer (score 0):

Finally solved the issue after run this command-:

```
npm i vue-loader
```

Answer (score 0):

what I did:

> 1. npm install
> 2. npm vue-loader
> 3. npm run watch

vue-loader is for webpack that allows you to author Vue components in a format called Single-File Components. You can read more [here](https://www.npmjs.com/package/vue-loader).